# Como saber a quantidade de NA em cada variável?

Tags: r

Suponha que eu esteja trabalhando com a seguinte base de dados:

```
df=data.frame(v=c(1,2,NA,4,NA,6,7,8,9,10),v2=c(11,NA,NA,14,NA,16,NA,NA,19,NA),
          v3=c(21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30),
          v4=c("a","b","c", NA, NA,NA,"g","h", NA,NA))
```

Preciso saber a quantidade de NA que cada variável contém. No exemplo:
v1=2
v2=6
v3=0

Eu poderia fazae o comando abaixo para cada variável

```
sum(is.na(df$v1))
```

Mas quando estamos com um grande data frame isso é nada prático.

Outro comando possível é o `summary(df)` mas como ele retorna muitos outros resultados fica difícil a visualização da quantidades de NA em cada variável.

Existe uma maneira de retornar apenas a quantidade de NAs que cada variável do data frame possui?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sapply` para aplicar a sua função a cada coluna do `data.frame`

```r
df
    v v2 v3   v4
1   1 11 21    a
2   2 NA 22    b
3  NA NA 23    c
4   4 14 24 <NA>
5  NA NA 25 <NA>
6   6 16 26 <NA>
7   7 NA 27    g
8   8 NA 28    h
9   9 19 29 <NA>
10 10 NA 30 <NA>

sapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
 v v2 v3 v4 
 2  6  0  5
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar a função `colwise` do `plyr` para tornar sua função aplicável às colunas do data frame:

Definindo a função:

```
library(plyr)
quantos.na <- colwise(function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

Aplicando a função:

```
quantos.na(df)
  v v2 v3 v4
1 2  6  0  5
```

Answer (score 2):

Tenta isso aqui

**table(data$VAR1, useNA = "always")**

O resultado aparece dessa forma:

```
 1      2     3     4     5     6     7  <NA> 

10484   518  4389  3639   272   522   836 18291
```

o comando **useNA = "always"** eh usado para que o R não omita os missings data.

Comment: É sempre bom explicar o porque de sua resposta.